# Solving this inequality without trial and error

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, inequality

> "What is the smallest value of $n$ such that an algorithm whose running time is $100n^2$ runs faster than an algorithm whose running time is $2^n$ on the same machine?"

I know the answer is  $n = 15$, but is there any way to solve this without trial and error?

Comment: have you tried with logarithms?

Comment: It should be $n=15$ since $2^{14}-100\cdot 14^2=-3216.$

Comment: You can start by [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+2%5Ex+-+100x%5E2+for+x%3D0+to+20) the function $x\mapsto 2^x - 100x^2$. After this, you just have to check that the value you found is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial and error is necessary, unless you use Lambert's W-function. In maple, the request for a solution to $2^x=100x^2$ gave two complicated expressions involving the Lambert function $W(x)$. Numeric evaluation of these gave the real values $0.103657...$ and $14.324727...$, making the answer $15$.